# Ruby: How to make IRB print structure for Arrays and Hashes

Tags: ruby, irb

When I make a new array/hash in **irb**, it prints out a nice format to show the structure, ex.

```
["value1", "value2", "value3"]
{"key1" => "value1"}
```

... but when I try to print out my variables using `puts`, I get them collapsed:

```
value1
value2
value3
key1
value1
```

I gather that `puts` is not the right command for what I want, but what is?  I want to be able to view my variables in **irb** in the first format, not the second.

Answer (score 122, accepted):

You can either use the `inspect` method:

```
a=["value1", "value2", "value3"]
puts a.inspect
```

Or, even better, use the pp (pretty print) lib:

```
require 'pp'
a=["value1", "value2", "value3"]
pp a
```

Comment: `pp` buys you indentation if object is too big.

Answer (score 61):

Another thing you can do is use the `y` method which converts input into Yaml. That produces pretty nice output...

```
>> data = { 'dog' => 'Flemeale', 'horse' => 'Gregoire', 'cow' => 'Fleante' }
=> {"cow"=>"Fleante", "horse"=>"Gregoire", "dog"=>"Flemeale"}
>> y data
--- 
cow: Fleante
horse: Gregoire
dog: Flemeale
```

Comment: Nice one, didn't know it (I just love YAML)

Comment: For 1.9 and later, instead of the `y` method , you should use `YAML.dump`. Per [https://github.com/tenderlove/psych/issues/50]: `y` polluted Kernel, and per [https://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/2332227], `Kernel.y` is private.

Answer (score 16):

The pretty print works well, but the [Awesome_Print](https://github.com/michaeldv/awesome_print) gem is even better! You will have to  `require awesome_print` but it handles nested hashes and arrays beautifully plus colors them in the Terminal using 'ap' instead of 'p' to puts the output.

You can also include it in your ~/.irbrc to have this as the default method for displaying objects:

```
require "awesome_print"
AwesomePrint.irb!
```

Comment: I like this one, nice looking Hashes!

Answer (score 6):

Try .inspect

```
>> a = ["value1", "value2", "value3"]
=> ["value1", "value2", "value3"]
>> a.inspect
=> "[\"value1\", \"value2\", \"value3\"]"
>> a = {"key1" => "value1"}
=> {"key1"=>"value1"}
>> a.inspect
=> "{\"key1\"=>\"value1\"}"
```

You can also use the p() method to print them:

```
>> p a
{"key1"=>"value1"}
```

Answer (score 2):

My personal tool of choice for this is 'Pretty Print' and the `pp` method

```
require 'pp' # <- 'Pretty Print' Included in ruby standard library
pp({ :hello => :world, :this => ['is', 'an', 'array'] })
=> {:hello=>:world, :this=>["is", "an", "array"]}
```

Comment: It doesn't format more complex hashes at all