# Printing array of arrays, each internal on separate line

Tags: ruby

Showing my interactive irb session:

```
2.3.0 :005 > ('a'..'c').to_a.combination(2).to_a
=> [["a", "b"], ["a", "c"], ["b", "c"]]

2.3.0 :006 > ('a'..'c').to_a.combination(2).to_a.each do |arr|
2.3.0 :007 >     puts arr
2.3.0 :008?>   end
a
b
a
c
b
c
=> [["a", "b"], ["a", "c"], ["b", "c"]]
```

How can I get this array of arrays to show each internal array on separate line, like so..?

```
["a", "b"]
["a", "c"]
["b", "c"]
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ruby: How to make IRB print structure for Arrays and Hashes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/703049/ruby-how-to-make-irb-print-structure-for-arrays-and-hashes)

Comment: Thanks for the ✅, but in future consider waiting longer before making a selection. Other members may have been working on answers and you don't want to discourage other answers. The point is, there's no rush. Many here wait at least a couple of hours before awarding the greenie.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [Kernel#p](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Kernel.html#method-i-p) rather than [Kernel#puts](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Kernel.html#method-i-puts).

```
('a'..'c').to_a.combination(2).each { |a| p a }
["a", "b"]
["a", "c"]
["b", "c"]
```

Note that, while [Array#combination](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-combination) without a block returns an enumerator, you don't have to convert it to an array before `each`'ing it.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
('a'..'c').to_a.combination(2).each do |arr|
   puts arr.inspect
end
```

Comment: No need for the second `to_a`.

Comment: You could also do `puts ('a'..'c').to_a.combination(2).map(&:inspect)`.

Answer (score 1):

Use [Kernel#pp](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.1/libdoc/pp/rdoc/PP.html#method-c-pp) from the Ruby [PP](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.1/libdoc/pp/rdoc/PP.html) (pretty print) library.  pp is like [Kernel#p](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Kernel.html#method-i-p):

```
require "pp"

pp ('a'..'e').to_a.combination(2).to_a
# => [["a", "b"], ["a", "c"], ["b", "c"]]
```

except that *pp* automatically splits long output onto multiple lines:

```
pp ('a'..'e').to_a.combination(2).to_a

[["a", "b"],
 ["a", "c"],
 ["a", "d"],
 ["a", "e"],
 ["b", "c"],
 ["b", "d"],
 ["b", "e"],
 ["c", "d"],
 ["c", "e"],
 ["d", "e"]]
```

Since Array#combination returns an Enumeration, we used #to_a to convert it to an array.  Without the #to_a, *pp* just shows this:

```
pp ('a'..'e').to_a.combination(2)
# => #<Enumerator: ...>
```

which is probably not what is wanted.