# Is there a Ruby method to print an object to the console in a way that is easy to read?

Tags: ruby

I understand that one can use something like `object.inspect` to view an object's state in the console (or to whichever output one is using), but does there exist a built-in method or a gem which provides a method to print out the object's state in an easy-to-read fashion?

Example:

```rb
> some_blog_post_object.beautiful_inspect
=> "title:    'Some Amazing Title'
    subtitle: 'Hopefully I'm not down-voted for n00b-ness'
    image:    'some_image.jpg'
           .
           .
           .
   "
```

Or something along these lines.

Comment: Perhaps not quite what you want, but you can try the built-in pretty-printer: `require 'pp'` ... `pp some_blog_post_object`

Comment: If `pp` doesn't work for you, then there may be a gem. Try Google searching on "ruby gem pretty print objects". I just tried that and saw a few promising links.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ruby: How to make IRB print structure for Arrays and Hashes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/703049/ruby-how-to-make-irb-print-structure-for-arrays-and-hashes)

Comment: I didn't know it was called "pretty printing". Great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://github.com/awesome-print/awesome_print can be a good fit. I recommend to combine it with `pry`.

Comment: awesome_print seems to be exactly what I'm looking for.